# DateTime parse not working as expected

Tags: ruby, parsing, datetime

I have Ruby code that looks vaguely like this.

```
str = 2010-12-02_12-10-26
puts str
puts DateTime.parse(str, "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
```

I expected to get the actual time from the parse. Instead, I'm getting output like this...

```
2010-12-02_12-10-26
2010-12-02T00:00:00+00:00
```

How do I get the time parsed in as well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works:

```
str = "2010-12-02_12-10-26"
puts str
puts DateTime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
```

This example on [Codepad](http://codepad.org/LcWydY5t).

According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse) `parse`:

> Create a new DateTime object by parsing from a String, without specifying the format.

And `strptime`:

> Create a new DateTime object by parsing from a String according to a specified format.

Answer (score 1):

Use strptime instead of parse

```
puts DateTime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
```